# Twisted not working for all users?

Tags: python, twisted

I am working on a "chat-like" server using Twisted in Python. However I am having issues. On the main admin account of my Mac, Twisted works fine. But when I go onto a separate admin account, I get thrown...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Alec/Desktop/server.py", line 1, in <module>
    from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol, Factory
ImportError: No module named twisted.internet.protocol
```

It works fine on the other account, but this new admin account doesn't work. I am working hard to get my project going, but this has me at a halt.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you verified if `sys.path` is the same for both users ?

Comment: @icecrime No, how do you do that?

Comment: `>>> import sys`   `>>> "\n".join(sys.path)`

Comment: `>>> import sys`
`>>> sys.path`

Answer (score 1):

I can only guess at what's wrong with your setup, since you haven't provided much information.  However, the cause must be something to do with the way you're invoking `python`, since the default python on OS X has Twisted installed (as you may have noticed).

- Does your administrative user have a self-compiled Python?
- Is your administrative user using `virtualenv`, or any other environment-management tool that would remove `site-packages`?
- Did your administrative user install Python from python.org? (This is not completely compatible with the built-in system Python and will have different packages available.)

If `type -p python` in a shell doesn't print `/usr/bin/python`, then one of these is likely the case, but fixing it (in other words, un-doing whatever has been done) depends on which of these options has altered your default Python.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check if `sys.path` (the module search path) is the same for both users.

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
```

There may be a user specific `PYTHONPATH` environment variable which alters the behavior for one of the two users, although I'm not sure it could actually *break* the import.

Comment: Wow, they are both different. The one that works shows the correct directory while the other one shows beginning /opt/local/library

Comment: That could very well explain the import error. See [`sys.path` documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.path)

Comment: On the bad side, my python script is on my desktop and on the good side is in a folder on the desktop.

Comment: From the documentation: "As initialized upon program startup, the first item of this list, `path[0]`, is the directory containing the script that was used to invoke the Python interpreter. **If the script directory is not available (e.g. if the interpreter is invoked interactively or if the script is read from standard input), `path[0]` is the empty string, which directs Python to search modules in the current directory first**."

I can't really help you more based on the information you provide.

Comment: Well, that isn't coming in clear to me at all. I guess I'll figure it out. Thanks.